# What is an example of a lower semicontinuous function that is not continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I couldn't find an example anywhere. Does anyone know such example? Thanks.

Comment: just think of the ceiling function.

Comment: The indicator function of any open set is lower semi-continuous; this provides lots of examples. (And the indicator function of a closed set is upper semi-continuous.)

Answer (score 11):

A useful exercise would be to look at these two functions:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad & x<0 \\ 1, & x\ge 0\end{cases}$$

$$g(x) = \begin{cases} 0, \quad & x\le0 \\ 1, & x\gt 0\end{cases}$$

One of these is upper semi-continuous and the other is lower semi-continuous. Clearly they only differ when $x=0$, and it would be useful for you to examine the definition of lower semi-continuous very careful for each one to decide which is which.

Comment: Thanks for the simple examples :)

Answer (score -1):

$f(x)=[x]$ such that $f(x)=1$  if  $x<1$; and  $f(x)=2$ if $x=1$; and $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ if $ x>1$.